# Using sed to delete multiple lines after match from second occurrence onwards

Tags: sed

sample.txt file:

```
template one
blah blah
blah blah
end
```

The sample file contains many same templates like this one and i'm using sed to delete all the replicas except the first one

```
system ("sed -ie '/template one/,+717d' $file");
```

can someone suggest how can I skip the first match

Comment: What are you calling `system()` from - perl, awk, or something else? Whyy do you think you need to call sed from that tool to do this? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for how to format your input, output, and code and make sure to add the expected output given your posted sample input and script. Make sure you post a [mcve] - not something 717+ lines long!

Comment: Poorly described problem. Perhaps what you looking for is `uniq sample.txt` -- update description of the problem in more clear way.

Answer (score 1):

The `addr1,+N` syntax is a GNU extension, so presumably you have GNU sed.

If so, then you can use its `0,addr2` syntax:

```
sed -ie '0,/template one/b; //,+717d'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can avoid shelling out to `sed` using `system` from within a Perl script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $N = 717; # number of lines to delete from the template
my $j = 0;   # template number
my $i = 0;   # current line within the template
while (<<>>) { # Note: double diamond op. requires perl>=5.22
    if (/template one/) {
        $i  = 1;
        $j++;
    }
    elsif ( $i > 0) {
        if ( $i <= $N) {
            $i++;
        }
        else {
            $i = 0;
        }
    }
    print if ($i == 0) || ($i > 0 && $j == 1);
}
```